# How to add own code to existing code without modifying it?

Tags: java

I am newbie in programming, so please explain simply.

I 've got a big GNU project written in java containing more than 1000 source files. I am using netbeans and I would like to apply my own changes in some of those files, but I want to have my own code seperate from what is already written. For example there is a file "Formula.java" that contains code around 5000 lines. If I make some changes to it, it will be really hard to find where my code resides later. In the beginning it was really simple because I had to edit less than 5 files. But now I have more than 20 and I am lost in the code, because I don't remember to what functions I made the changes inside the classes. My question is:

How can I have my function implementations seperate from what is already written, but having my code overriding the functionality of some targetted functions.

Comment: This is why version control is your friend.

Comment: Start learning git! http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Answer (score 1):

some Version control system can remember the change for you . Version control system like svn

Comment: I am now starting to learn how to use svn, maybe that helps me seperate my code and manage it easier.

Answer (score 0):

U can inherit the class, use extends keyword, 
like "public class  MyFormula extends Formula"
now U can write an override method in MyFormula.java without changing Formula.java

Comment: This can work sometimes but is not a good general approach for modifying third party code. Sometimes you really need to patch it, and that's when version control comes in.

Comment: I thought about it, but the whole project is using and creating objects from the "Formula" class, and has no clue for my new created "MyFormula" class.

Comment: I really found what I was looking for. I used the refactor -> extract superclass tool in netbeans. It creates a superclass "MyFormula" and a selection is given to extract functions/members from "Formula". I can now make my own implementation for the extracted functions and let the "Formula" class to be the subclass and do the rest :D . Thanks for all the answers. I really don't want to use the "MyFormula" class anywhere, I just want the "Formula" class to have different implementation in some functions, that I can make in my superclass now, but my superclass contains only those functions.